# Convert my def view to class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this view in my app:

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            contact_website = form.cleaned_data['contact_website']
            contact_subject = form.cleaned_data['contact_subject']
            form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            template = get_template('contact/contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({'contact_name': contact_name,
                               'contact_email': contact_email,
                               'contact_website': contact_website,
                               'contact_subject': contact_subject,
                               'form_content': form_content, })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "www.inexistente.com" + '<support@inexistente.com>',
                ['mymail@gmail.com'],
                headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {'form': form_class, })
```

I want to transform this to a class based view, I believe that is "more organized" for me...

- What generic Django view to use?
- Do you believe that is recommended to do this?
- In the view, Is recommended use this code at the end to renew the form in case of not passing?

*"else:
        form = form_class()"*

i was trying without that code and my form renews itself perfectly.

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something, any contribution is wellcome, Thanks for evaluate!

Comment: Your code would already be more "organized" if you got rid of the redundant parts. For example, there's no need to assign all the cleaned data fields to separate variables, only to put them straight back into a dictionary to pass to Context; just pass in `cleaned_data` directly.

Comment: I really do not know what to say. Use ccbv.co.uk and experiment

Comment: You're absolutely right Daniel, I ignored my shortcoming. thank you both for your recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a view that displays a form and which redisplays the form with validation errors on error and redirects to a new URL on success, you can use `FormView` generic view.

Your FBV code converted to CBV:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class Contact(FormView):

    form_class = ContactForm  # Form class to be used
    template_name = 'contact/contact.html' # Template to be used
    success_url = '/'  # Redirect to this url when form is valid

    def form_valid(self, form):
        template = get_template('contact/contact_template.txt')
        context_dict = form.cleaned_data
        context_dict['form_content'] = form.cleaned_data['content'] 
        context = Context(context_dict)             
        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "www.inexistente.com" + '<support@inexistente.com>',
                ['mymail@gmail.com'],
                headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
            )
        email.send()
        return super(Contact, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here,
`form_class`: defines the form class to be used.
`template_name`: defines the template to be used to display the form.
`success_url`: defines the url to be used when the form is valid.

You can put all the logic for the code to be executed when form is valid inside the `form_valid()` function. After performing all the operations, call the `super()` which redirects to the `success_url` defined in your class.

Also, when you are building context to be passed to the email template, you can  use the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary. All the keys you have used to build the context dictionary is same as in the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary except the `form_content` key. So, i have just used the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary and added an extra key `form_content` in a  `context_dict` dictionary which will be then used in the email template for rendering.